# Plotting the Average Line of multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, sum, average

Look I'm sure this has been asked before, but I've hit another wall, I would like to plot the average line over multiple lines on a plot. I can't seem to be able to do do it after many hours of attempts. I know it looks lazy and I'm super sorry but please help a brother out im at the end of my wits. I would just like the average lines plotted over all of the experimental lines. I've tried using rowMeans, and tried to generate new data frames by grouping my data with no success.please.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m1ao29xaudksanf/e1.txt?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0sf3hew2pco73s/c1.txt?dl=0

```
cc1L3 <- read.table('./Colony 1 Location 3/c1.txt', header=TRUE)
ec1L3 <- read.table('./Colony 1 Location 3/e1.txt', header=TRUE)
Col1Loc3 <- ggplot()+
geom_smooth(data=ec1L3, aes(Time,Current1, colour= 'experimental1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=ec1L3, aes(Time,Current2, colour= 'experimental1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=ec1L3, aes(Time,Current3, colour= 'experimental1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=ec1L3, aes(Time,Current4, colour= 'experimental1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=ec1L3, aes(Time,Current5, colour= 'experimental1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=ec1L3, aes(Time,Current6, colour= 'experimental1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=ec1L3, aes(Time,Current7, colour= 'experimental1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=ec1L3, aes(Time,Current8, colour= 'experimental1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=ec1L3, aes(Time,Current9, colour= 'experimental1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=ec1L3, aes(Time,Current10, colour= 'experimental1L3'))+
###############
geom_smooth(data=cc1L3, aes(Time,Current1, colour='control1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=cc1L3, aes(Time,Current2, colour='control1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=cc1L3, aes(Time,Current3, colour='control1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=cc1L3, aes(Time,Current4, colour='control1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=cc1L3, aes(Time,Current5, colour='control1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=cc1L3, aes(Time,Current6, colour='control1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=cc1L3, aes(Time,Current7, colour='control1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=cc1L3, aes(Time,Current8, colour='control1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=cc1L3, aes(Time,Current9, colour='control1L3'))+
geom_smooth(data=cc1L3, aes(Time,Current10, colour='control1L3'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but perhaps you want something like this:

```
cc1L3 <- read.table('https://www.dropbox.com/s/m1ao29xaudksanf/e1.txt?dl=1', header=TRUE)
ec1L3 <- read.table('https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0sf3hew2pco73s/c1.txt?dl=1', header=TRUE)

library(dplyr)

df <- bind_rows(
  control = gather(cc1L3, variable, value, -Time),
  experimental = gather(ec1L3, variable, value, -Time),
  .id = 'treatment'
)

ggplot(df, aes(Time, value, color = treatment)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = interaction(variable, treatment)), se = FALSE, size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, size = 2)
```

Reshaping your data is crucial.

[image]

Comment: I think you read the files in reverse. You assigned the one named "c1.txt" to `ec1L3` and vice versa

Comment: Ah sorry,  yes I did. Does it matter for the actual solution? Surely you can take it from here?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I assume they can switch it back

Answer (score 0):

What About calculating the `mean()` separately ?

```
ec1L3$mean <- apply(ec1L3[2:ncol(ec1L3)],1, mean) # Calculating by row the mean
cc1L3$mean <- apply(cc1L3[2:ncol(cc1L3)],1, mean) # Calculating by row the mean
## Add each line to each graphic 
geom_smooth(data=ec1L3, aes(Time,mean, colour= 'experimental1L3'))
geom_smooth(data=cc1L3, aes(Time,mean, colour= 'control1L3'))
```

I hope it helps. Cheers !

Comment: Note that there is a `rowMeans` function! Also your apply call errors for me, `2:ncol(ec1L3)` is just a vector from 2 to 11....

Comment: Yes, because the first column of his dataset is the x line

Comment: But your not `apply`ing the function to the data, you are applying to `2:11`. Perhaps you were trying to do e.g. `apply(ec1L3[2:ncol(ec1L3)],1, mean)`

Comment: You are right on that one. I did not see that mistake of mine. I have corrected it :)